# What language to use instead of Español Latinoamericano and Flemish aka Nederlands (België)

Tags: android, localization

My application must play greetings phrase, e.g. "Hello". This message is played in different languages - it can be configured by the user in proprietary application settings (I use http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html for retrieving language wording).

Two of languages that user must be able to set are:

- Español Latinoamericano
- Flemish

None of those languages are available in Android.
For Flemish it's quite simple as I use "*Nederlands (België)*", Android ISO code is nl_BE.
But I have problem with Español Latinoamericano, possible options are:

- "*Español (México)*", Android ISO code is es_MX
- "*Español (Estados Unidos)*", Android ISO code is es_US
- "*Español*", Android ISO code is es
- use proprietary wording "*Español Latinoamericano*"

None of this option seems to be good, any other options?

Answer (score 0):

According to [BCP 5646](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5646) (Tags for Identifying Languages), formally just an Internet Best Current Practices document, but widely regarded as applicable more widely too, the code for Latin American Spanish is es-419. Using the underscore syntax, that would be es_419. The code 419 covers in principle “Latin America and the Caribbean”.

Whether this code is supported is a different issue. But for text data like “Hello”, I don’t think there is a reason to distinguish between generic Spanish and particular forms of Spanish.

Comment: "Hello" is only an example, the phrase is more sophisticated. Furthermore the phrase is a voice phrase, not just text on the screen, so even "Hello" is pronounced differently in "Español" and in "Español Latinoamericano"

Answer (score 0):

If you make a quick search for "*Español Latinoamericano*" (in english or whatever you want), you will find that this sort of language comes from Spanish ([link 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Community_of_Latin_American_and_Caribbean_States) and [link 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_America)) and is talked by all the ex-Spain colonies.

So if "Español" isn't enough, you have to define a folder and a file **strings.xml** for each eighteen Spanish-speaking countries, for example:

- values-es-rAR (this is for Argentina)
- values-es-rCO (this is for Colombia)
- values-es-rUY (this is for Uruguay)
- and so go on

Hope it helps.

Comment: "Español" is not a good idea because I have to distinguish between  "Español" and "Español Latinoamericano" - both options will be on the same list, user hast to tell the difference when selecting.

Comment: @MarianPaździoch you can do difference with "Español" and "Español Latinoamericano" by adding also "values-es" to the folders I described above.